# How can i change color of a selected item in a v-select (Vuetify 3, Vue 3)

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm working on a Vue 3 project and we're using Vuetify. We're using `<v-select multiple>` and we want to change the color of elements when they're selected. My problem is that I don't know why but I can't change the color for an item when its selected.
For example I want something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctpW7.png).

I try to add this :

```css
.v-list .v-list-item--link:before{
  background-color: $primary !important;
}
.theme--light.v-list-item:hover::before { opacity: 0.64; }
```

I also try this :

```css
.v-list-item--active {
     background-color: $primary;
}
```

but this didn't work.

There is my code :

```html
<template>
  <section>
    <v-form
      v-model="valid"
      @submit.prevent="addPost"
    >
      <v-card class="form">
        <v-card-title>
          {{ $gettext('Blog post addition') }}
        </v-card-title>
        <v-card-text>
          <v-select
            v-model="categories"
            variant="underlined"
            :label="$gettext('Categories')"
            :items="avail_categories"
            item-title="name"
            return-object
            multiple
            chips
            color="primary"
          />
        </v-card-text>
      </v-card>
    </v-form>
  </section>
</template>
```